# Change the Excel.Button.Caption property inside of a loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code below attached to a button in Excel. When the button is clicked, I would like to display a countdown by changing the Caption of the button to "5... 4... 3... 2... 1... 0" and waiting 1 second between each change. The "i" variable holds the countdown second.

The cell to which I'm writing "i" displays the countdown correctly, but the button caption only changes when it gets to "0". It doesn't display the intermediate values.

Why does the button text not change until after the loop is finished?

```
Sub Timer()
    Const COUNTDOWN As Integer = 5

    Dim testButton As Excel.Button
    Set testButton = Application.ActiveSheet.Buttons("TestButton")
    testButton.Select

    For i = COUNTDOWN To 0 Step -1
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = i
        testButton.Caption = i
        Call Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I have tested this in Excel 2016 and it is working on both countdowns of the ActiveCell and also the testButton caption. They are displaying each number as it counts down. What version of excel are you using?

Comment: Excel for Mac Version 15.41

Answer (score 1):

Likely some repaint isn't happening, whatever the reason is (assuming `Application.ScreenUpdating` isn't turned off... which shouldn't be the case, since the cell value does get updated).

Add a `DoEvents` call after the `Caption` assignment.

```
For i = COUNTDOWN To 0 Step -1
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = i
    testButton.Caption = i
    DoEvents '<~ let Excel process what just happened
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Next i
```

That will also let Excel process any pending events and Windows messages.

Comment: The DoEvents call doesn't make a difference for me. Likely it is some Excel for Mac issue.

Comment: Specifying it was a Mac from the start would have helped... Mac and ActiveX don't really play well. Replace the button with a shape (you'll get a much nicer looking button anyway), and assign it to a macro instead of handling its `Click` event. You'll be able to access it through the `Shapes` collection of your worksheet; declare a `Shape` object to access its properties, including its text content.